Running the command pip install email results in the following output and error message:
Collecting email
  Using cached email-4.0.2.tar.gz (1.2 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [26 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\User\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
          ~~~~^^
        File "C:\Users\User\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\User\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-beuu5eq3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 332, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=[])
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-beuu5eq3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 302, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-beuu5eq3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 503, in run_setup
          super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-beuu5eq3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 318, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
          ~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-w59lbqj9\email_11f37c5ebb9c436d838962f02bdbe4f0\ez_setup.py", line 91
          except pkg_resources.VersionConflict, e:
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      SyntaxError: multiple exception types must be parenthesized
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

C:\Users\User>python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\user\lib\site-packages (24.2)
Collecting setuptools
  Using cached setuptools-74.1.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.7 kB)
Using cached setuptools-74.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (1.3 MB)
Installing collected packages: setuptools
Successfully installed setuptools-74.1.2

What I did: I tried to ask the neural network for a solution, reinstalled python, manually downloaded the email
